# Is a constructor always present in a class?

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor

When I create class without constructor and with constructor, the IL code doesn't change. Am I wrong in thinking that there is always constructor present?

```cs
namespace Test13
{
    class Human
    {

    }
}
```

In the following IL code, the line -

`IL_0001: call         instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()`

makes a call to a constructor without declaring constructor.

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit
  Test13.Human
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void
    .ctor() cil managed
  {
    .maxstack 8

    // [11 9 - 11 23]
    IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
    IL_0001: call         instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006: nop

    // [12 9 - 12 10]
    IL_0007: nop

    // [14 9 - 14 10]
    IL_0008: ret

  } // end of method Human::.ctor
} // end of class DecompilationLearn.Human
```

If someone can clear this up to me, thanks.

Comment: yes there is a default parameterless if we don't define one

Comment: Note that static classes do *not* have any constructors, however.

Comment: What would happen if there were no constructor?  How would you use (create an instance of) the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

If you don't provide any constructor yourself, the compiler will add a public default (parameterless) one during compilation, which will be generated in IL code.

When you create an object of a class, you call the constructor of that class after the `new` keyword -

```cs
Human human = new Human();
```

Therefore, any class that you can create an object of, must have a constructor. That is why, if you don't provide a constructor to `Human` class, the compiler provides one to make sure you can instantiate the class, as mentioned in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors#parameterless-constructors) -

> If you don't provide a constructor for your class, C# creates one by
> default that instantiates the object and sets member variables to the
> default values ...

For static classes there's an exception (as mentioned by @JonSkeet in the comments) - static classes cannot have a constructor with *any* access modifier. That's because you are not allowed to create an object of a static class.

The IL code you mentioned is not making -

> a call to constructor without declaring constructor

Instead, it is calling the constructor of the base class (`System.Object`) of `Human`, and that call is taking place inside the `Human` constructor that the compiler has generated for you.

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed correctly and [MSDN confirms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) in the section "Parameterless constructors":

> If you don't provide a constructor for your class, C# creates one by default

Answer (score 2):

If you don't define a constructor in c#, the C# compiler automatically creates one public parameterless constructor in the class.

[Constructors - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)